# Find MMT Unicode abbreviations for given symbol (e.g. given ☞, find "juri")

Tags: intellij-idea, unicode, editor, mmt

The usual IDEs/editors for MMT (e.g. [IntelliJ + MMT plugin](https://uniformal.github.io//doc/applications/intellij/index.html) or [jEdit](https://uniformal.github.io/doc/applications/jedit.html)) feature an autocompletion feature for certain useful Unicode characters. For instance, I can type <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and immediately get suggested `jleftrightarrow` that, upon autocompletion, is replaced by `↔`.

Is there a way to find out the reverse association? E.g. I have the symbol `☞` at hand and would like to know the autocompletion abbreviation starting with `j` — if it exists. For that hand, I would get `juri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MMT OnlineTools I developed allow this: https://comfreek.github.io/mmteditor.

See screenshot below: if you already have a string full of Unicode symbols that you don't know how to type, just paste it under *"how do I type X?"*. And if you are looking for a specific abbreviation — by Unicode character or by (parts of its) name — use the *"abbreviation search"* feature.

Internally, my tools pulls from (a copy of) the same [resource file](https://github.com/UniFormal/MMT/blob/master/src/mmt-api/resources/unicode/unicode-latex-map) that Dennis linked in his answer.

[image: Screenshot of the MMT Online Tools]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there currently isn't a good way to look up or search for the ASCII abbreviations, except to go straight for the source — which at least has the advantage that it's guaranteed to be up-to-date.

The IDE plugins all have access to an `mmt.jar` and load their abbreviations from a specific resource file embedded therein. You can find it here on GitHub: https://github.com/UniFormal/MMT/blob/master/src/mmt-api/resources/unicode/unicode-latex-map.

In the long term, we should consider extending that file with a third "field" that gives a short description, and e.g. have a text field in IntelliJ to search for a specific abbreviation.